# Mostrar/Ocultar um parágrafo com Js

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
HTML
<div class="about" id="about">
    <h1>Sobre</h1>
    <a href="" class="aboutBtn">Ler Conteúdo</a>
    <p class="textAbout">Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>

Js
const aboutBtn = document.querySelector(".aboutBtn");
const textAbout = document.querySelector(".textAbout");

aboutBtn.addEventListener("click", function (evento) {
    evento.preventDefault();
    textAbout.style.display = "block";
});
```

Eu fiz isso, porém não sei como posso fazer para ocultar o parágrafo quando o usuário clicar novamente no botão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto faz o que você quer:

```
textAbout.style.display = 'none' === textAbout.style.display ? 'block' : 'none';
```

Isso quer dizer que quando `textAbout.style.display` for `'none'`, o clique vai mudar para `'block'`, e vice-versa.

Mas atenção que, na situação apresentada no seu código, inicialmente  o valor não é `'none'` nem `'block'`, mas sim `''`. Então, se a condição fosse ao contrário (checar se é `'block'` e, vez de checar se é `'none'`), o primeiro clique não funcionaria (colocaria `'block'` em vez de `'none'`). Importante saber também que se a propriedade `display` do elemento não tiver sido definida inline (e sim num CSS separado, com classe ou outro seletor que pegue o elemento em questão), o valor de `style.display` será `''`, e não o que estiver definido no CSS. O atributo style só mexe no que é definido inline. É por esse e outros motivos que...

## Vou recomendar que você faça de outro jeito

Alterar o `style` diretamente não é uma boa ideia na maioria dos casos. Conforme você vai querendo fazer coisas mais complexas, vai ficando uma bagunça. Eu recomendo tratar tudo que é estilo só no CSS, e usar JS apenas para colocar ou tirar classes definidas nesse CSS. Por exemplo:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const p = document.querySelector('p');

btn.addEventListener( 'click', e => p.classList.toggle('escondido'), false );
```

```css
.escondido {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Clique aqui</button>
<p>texto que some e aparece</p>
```

O método `toggle` da lista de classes faz exatamente o que você quer, coloca a classe caso não tenha, e retira se tiver. Tem também os métodos `add`, `remove` e `contains`, que podem ser úteis. Mais detalhes na [documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: Ah sim, eu esqueci de colocar que no css eu já deixei esse parágrafo com display none.
Obrigado.

Comment: Veja a edição que fiz agora, tem uma forma melhor de fazer

Comment: Ahhh obrigadooo